# ansible integer type variable doesn't work but direct number does

Tags: api, ansible, uri, portainer

There is an ansible task using [uri module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) and [portainer API](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/portainer/portainer-ce/2.6.3#/endpoints/EndpointCreate) with following body:

```yaml
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    body_format: json
    headers:
      accept: application/json
      Content-Type: multipart/form-data
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ portainer_auth['json']['jwt'] }}"
    body:
      Name: "{{ item['Name'] }}"
      EndpointCreationType: "{{ item['EndpointCreationType'] }}"
      URL: "{{ item['URL'] | default(omit, true) | string }}"
      PublicURL: "{{ item['PublicURL'] | default(omit, true) }}"
      GroupID: "{{ item['GroupID'] }}"
```

that throws error:

```json
"json": "cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field endpointUpdatePayload.GroupID of type int", 
"message": "Invalid request payload"
```

However this works so the problem seems to be in ansible variable

```yaml
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    body_format: json
    headers:
      accept: application/json
      Content-Type: multipart/form-data
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ portainer_auth['json']['jwt'] }}"
    body:
      Name: "{{ item['Name'] }}"
      EndpointCreationType: "{{ item['EndpointCreationType'] }}"
      URL: "{{ item['URL'] | default(omit, true) | string }}"
      PublicURL: "{{ item['PublicURL'] | default(omit, true) }}"
      GroupID: 2
```

When `body_format: form-multipart` then the error is

```json
"json": "details": "invalid character '-' in numeric literal", 
"message": "Invalid request payload"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `"{{ item['GroupID'] | int }}"`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue.

It seem that you faormating method is wrong.
Also you forgot method for URI.

Try this:

```yaml
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: <portainer_server_url>:<portainer_port>/api/endpoints # default port 9000
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body_format: form-multipart
    headers:
      accept: application/json
      Content-Type: multipart/form-data
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ {{ (auth_token.content|from_json).jwt }}"
    body:
      Name: "{{ item.Name }}"
      EndpointCreationType: "{{ item.EndpointCreationType }}"
      URL: "{{ item.URL | string }}"
      PublicURL: "{{ item.PublicURL | default(omit, true) }}"
      GroupID: 2
   with_items:
    - "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].endpoints }}"
```

With inventory structure like this (yaml):

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    node01:
      endpoints:
        - Name: local
          EndpointCreationType: 1
          URL: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
          PublicURL: <node1_IP|FQDN>
        - Name: node02
          EndpointCreationType: 1
          URL: "tcp://<node02_IP|FQDN:<docker_API_port>" default port= 2375
          PublicURL: <node02_IP|FQDN>
```

It works fine for me ;-)